# Prove $\tan^2\frac{\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{3\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{7\pi}{16} = 28$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I came across this question the other day and need some direction on part (b).

Given the identity

$$ \tan 4\theta = \dfrac{4\tan\theta - 4\tan^3\theta}{1 - 6\tan^2\theta + \tan^4\theta} $$

(a) Use this identity to show the equation

$$ x^4 + 4x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0 $$

has distinct roots

$$ x = \tan\frac{\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}  $$

b) **Hence** show that

$$ \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{3\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16}+\tan^2\frac{7\pi}{16} = 28
$$

Part (a) is fine.  I just substituted $ x = \tan \theta$, then

$$ \tan 4\theta = \dfrac{4x - 4x^3}{1 - 6x^2 + x^4} $$

when $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{16}$

$$  \tan 4\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{16} = \dfrac{4x - 4x^3}{1 - 6x^2 + x^4} $$

$$  \tan \dfrac{\pi}{4} = \dfrac{4x - 4x^3}{1 - 6x^2 + x^4} $$

$$  1 = \dfrac{4x - 4x^3}{1 - 6x^2 + x^4} $$

$$ x^4 + 4x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0 $$

So the roots are when $ \tan 4\theta = 1 $

$$  \tan 4\theta = 1 $$

$$  4\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}, \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi + \big( \pi + \frac{\pi}{4} \big) $$

$$ \theta = \frac{\pi}{16}, \frac{5\pi}{16}, \frac{9\pi}{16},  \frac{13\pi}{16}  $$

Since $ x = \tan \theta $

$$ \tan \theta = \tan\frac{\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{9\pi}{16},  \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}  $$

$$ x = \tan\frac{\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}, \tan\frac{9\pi}{16},  \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}  $$

I require some direction in Part (b) using the above information.  I could simply use trig identities and transform $\tan \theta = \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ (I think), but that defeats the purpose.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to use the relations between the coefficients and the roots. Here the sum of the roots is -4, and the sum of the product of roots (taken two at a time) is =-6.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @ShyamalSayak.  As a (problem-composer-unintended) less elegant alternative, note that any (**symmetric**) 4th degree polynomial equation of the form $$x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 - ax + 1 = 0 \implies x^2 + ax + b - \frac{a}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0 ~: ~x \neq 0$$ can be defeated by the substitution $$w = x - \frac{1}{x} \implies w^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} - 2.$$  So, you can convert the original equation into a quadratic equation in $~w~$ and then solve for $~w.$

Comment: @Stephan: Are you aware of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)? The problem in (b) asks to show that for the polynomial in (a), we have $P_2=28$. Using $P_1=e_1$ and $P_2=e_1P_1-2e_2$ and Vieta's formulas to find $e_1=-4,e_2=-6$, we have $P_2=(-4)^2-2(-6)=16+12=28$

Comment: No I am not away of Newton's identities.  I'll look that up.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ We know that

$$(a+b+c+d)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd)$$

Use Vieta's formulas to figure out what each of the parenthetical quantities are.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I thought Vieta's formulas was the key to solving this question.  I'll post my answer when I get figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help.  As suspected I used Vieta's formulas to help prove:

$$ \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{3\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{7\pi}{16} = 28 $$

Given the original quadratic:

$$ x^4 + 4x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0 $$

with factors

$$ x = \tan\frac{\pi}{16}, x = \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}, x = \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}, x = \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}
$$

The quartic is in the form

$$ ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0 $$

Vieta's formula for quartics with roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ is:

$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = - \dfrac{b}{a} $$

and

$$ \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \beta\gamma +\beta\delta + \gamma\delta = \frac{c}{a}
$$

Thus

$$  \tan\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan\frac{9\pi}{16} + \tan\frac{13\pi}{16} = -4  \label{eq:EQU1} \tag{1}
$$

Aslo

$$ \bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) = -6 
\label{eq:EQU2} \tag{2}
$$

Squaring $ \eqref{eq:EQU1} $

$$ \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{9\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{13\pi}{16} + 2\Bigg[\bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{5\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) +
\bigg( \tan\frac{9\pi}{16}\bigg) \bigg( \tan\frac{13\pi}{16}\bigg) \Bigg] = 16
$$

Using $ \eqref{eq:EQU2} $

$$  \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{9\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{13\pi}{16} + (2 \cdot -6) = 16
$$

$$  \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{9\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{13\pi}{16}  = 28
$$

Since

$$ \tan\frac{9\pi}{16} = \tan\big(\pi - \frac{7\pi}{16}\big) = -\tan \frac{7\pi}{16} $$

and

$$ \tan\frac{13\pi}{16} = \tan\big(\pi - \frac{3\pi}{16}\big) = -\tan \frac{3\pi}{16} $$

We get

$$  \tan^2\frac{\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{3\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{5\pi}{16} + \tan^2\frac{7\pi}{16}  = 28
$$

Thanks everyone!